# Where should I connect the V_REF1 & V_REF2 if I want to implement this two stage operational amplifier to a bandgap reference?

Tags: operational-amplifier, biasing

This is just a very elementary question for you. But for me it is new.

I have found this subthreshold op-amp which is a work by Engineers, **Sumukh Nitundil, Nihal Singh, R. Balaji, Pankaj Arora**.

I want to use their op-smp as a bandgap reference. Where should I connect the V_REF1 and V_REF2 ? (Since I thought that the only terminal used are the Vin- , Vin+ and Vout.)

The op-amp is not my Work. Refer to the names sbove.

The reference is [here](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/2012/2012.12088.pdf).

[image]

Comment: these bias points make certain resistors out of M5 and M6. this controls input and output quiscient current. you can balance current consumptions vs noise/gain preference.

Comment: *I want to use their op-smp as a bandgap reference.* You probably mean that you want to use this opamp **in** a bandgap reference **circuit**. An opamp cannot be a bandgap. Why use this opamp in particular? V_REF1 and VREF_2 aren't reference voltages, they're **biasing voltages**, it is confucing to call then reference voltages. Calling them reference voltages suggests that these voltages are **constant** which they are **NOT** (at least if you want a **constant biasing current**).

Comment: I suggest that you read the free Ebook "Designing Analog Chips"  http://www.designinganalogchips.com/  where you can find some examples including the biasing circuits. This book was written by Hans Camenzind, the designer of the NE555 timer chip.

Comment: This looks like a homework problem to me. Follow Bimpelrkkie's suggestion it will help you a lot.

Comment: Appreciate the suggestions I'm new in designing.

Comment: What I mean for that is I want to implement the Opamp to my Bandgap Ref, I think the moderator just edited my post yesterday.